# java.lang.IllegalStateException: no included points at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds$Builder

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, illegalstateexception

Getting an error on this line, as soon as I press pick

```
 LatLngBounds bounds=builder.build();
```

Tried many ways like using the browser API key instead of google maps api key

```
private void getDirection() {

        currentPosition= new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(),mLastLocation.getLongitude());
        String requestAPI=null;
        try{
            requestAPI="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?"+"mode=driving&"+
                    "transit_routing_preference=less_driving&"+"origin="+currentPosition.latitude+","+
                    currentPosition.longitude+"&"+"destination="+destination+"&"+"key="+getResources().getString(R.string.google_map_API_key);
            Log.d(TAG, "getDirection: requestAPI");
            mService.getPath(requestAPI)
                    .enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject(response.body().toString());
                                JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("routes");
                                for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                                    JSONObject route=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                    JSONObject poly=route.getJSONObject("overview_polyline");
                                    String polyline=poly.getString("points");
                                    polyLineList=decodePoly(polyline);
                                }
                                LatLngBounds.Builder builder= new LatLngBounds.Builder();
                                for(LatLng latLng:polyLineList)
                                    builder.include(latLng);
                                LatLngBounds bounds=builder.build();
                                CameraUpdate mcameraUpdate =CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds,2);
                                mMap.animateCamera(mcameraUpdate);

                                polylineOptions=new PolylineOptions();
                                polylineOptions.color(Color.GRAY);
                                polylineOptions.width(5);
                                polylineOptions.startCap(new SquareCap());
                                polylineOptions.endCap(new SquareCap());
                                polylineOptions.jointType(JointType.ROUND);
                                polylineOptions.addAll(polyLineList);
                                greyPolyline=mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);

                                blackpolylineOptions=new PolylineOptions();
                                blackpolylineOptions.color(Color.BLACK);
                                blackpolylineOptions.width(5);
                                blackpolylineOptions.startCap(new SquareCap());
                                blackpolylineOptions.endCap(new SquareCap());
                                blackpolylineOptions.jointType(JointType.ROUND);
                                blackPolyline=mMap.addPolyline(blackpolylineOptions);

                                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(polyLineList.get(polyLineList.size()-1))
                                        .title("Pickup Location"));

                                //Animation
                                ValueAnimator polyLineAnimator=ValueAnimator.ofInt(0,100);
                                polyLineAnimator.setDuration(2000);
                                polyLineAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
                                polyLineAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                                        List<LatLng> points=greyPolyline.getPoints();
                                        int percentvalue= (int) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                                        int size=points.size();
                                        int newpoints= (int) (size*(percentvalue/100.0f));
                                        List<LatLng> p=points.subList(0,newpoints);
                                        blackPolyline.setPoints(p);
                                    }
                                });

                                polyLineAnimator.start();

                                carMarker=mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(currentPosition)
                                .flat(true)
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.car)));

                                handler=new Handler();
                                index=-1;
                                next=1;
                                handler.postDelayed(drawPathRunnable,3000);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
```

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: no included points
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkState(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds$Builder.build(Unknown Source)
        at com.example.annapurna.rma.ui.MapsActivity$3.onResponse(MapsActivity.java:267)
        at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:71)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5776)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
03-30 18:54:01.903 30134-30134/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.annapurna.rma, PID: 30134
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: no included points
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkState(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds$Builder.build(Unknown Source)
        at com.example.annapurna.rma.ui.MapsActivity$3.onResponse(MapsActivity.java:267)
        at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:71)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5776)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// checking if polylineList is Empty or not    
if (!polyLineList.isEmpty()) {
        // Adjusting Bounds
        LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
        for (Latlng latLng : polyLineList) {
            builder.include(latLng);
        }
        LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
        CameraUpdate mCameraUpdate = 
        CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 2);
        mMap.animateCamera(mCameraUpdate);
    }
```

Comment: Since you are not checking if the polylineList is empty or not you are getting this exception. Try the above code and let me know if that worked for you!